# Is "oppido" (adverb) related to "oppidum"(noun)?

Tags: etymology

According to L&S, the etymology of *oppido* ([adverb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oppido#Adverb)) is

> adv. etym. dub.

where I imagine "dub" stands for something like "dubious". In any case, what can we speculate about the etymology of this word? In particular, is it in any way related to *oppidum* ([noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oppidum#Latin))? The two meanings are too apart for this to be the case, but languages oftentimes are surprising.

Comment: Especially because _oppidō_ has a long _ō_, which means it looks exactly like the ablative of _oppidum_, and ablative nouns are a common source of adverbs…

Comment: Looking at the etymology of _oppidum_ "ob + pedum: on or over the plain" (Wiktionary), it would seem that oppidō might be glossed as "outstandingly".

Comment: @Draconis but the meanings seem world apart. Is that also common? I'm very curious.

Comment: @ColinFine In the sense that a town "outstands" from the rest of the landscape of a plain? Might be the connection between the two.

Comment: @luchonacho: that's what I meant..

Comment: Well, we could always start with the TLL https://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#63245 and then de Vaan (s.v. oppidum), where he mentions an etymology proposed by Nussbaum - "Latin *oppidō* might be explained as *'to the ground' > 'utterly'" (p. 431).

Comment: For more info, there's Walde and Hoffmann https://archive.org/details/walde/page/n1123/mode/2up (p. 215) and Ernout and Meillet https://archive.org/details/DictionnaireEtymologiqueDeLaLangueLatine/page/n239/mode/2up (p. 463)